# Chrono : Different output for the same program using gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-chrono

This code displays different output for different versions of gcc compiler

```cpp
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace date;
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

using time_point_t = std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds>;

time_point_t parse_tp(std::string s) {
    time_point_t tp;
    std::istringstream in(s);
    in >> parse("%Y%m%d-%T", tp);
    return tp;
}

int
main()
{
    auto tp = parse_tp("20240304-13:00:00.002");
    std::set<time_point_t> s = {tp, tp + std::chrono::seconds(1)};
    std::cout << *std::ranges::lower_bound(s, tp + std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

| Compiler | Output |
| --- | --- |
| [gcc 13](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7mr0EAbHLicgrEdG) | `2024-03-04 13:00:01.002000` |
| [gcc trunk](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UszLcA3u2t2xKiUL) | `2024-03-04 13:00:01.001999` |

What makes the output different?

Is it a bug?

Comment: FWIW same result here: https://godbolt.org/z/89Mh4zd5a

Comment: As [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78109331/7582247) Yesterday, parse the microseconds separately and you'll get a better, and also the same, result in both gcc versions: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/eM95KG3v3)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes, but using the same code, I expected the same result..

Comment: Still investigating.  But I think the trunk version may be calling `std::chrono::parse` instead of `date::parse`.  Not sure yet.

Comment: Yes, that's it @HowardHinnant - I find it a little odd that by parsing the microseconds manually and then adding that duration to the time point, I get much better results - even when not rounding to closest _milli_ second but staying at the parsed microseconds.

Comment: Another (maybe not) interesting observation: https://godbolt.org/z/cbsGYWxcq. clang (trunk) with libc++ results agrees with gcc 13/clang 17.

Comment: I don't think llvm implements `std::chrono::parse` yet, so that will be calling `date::parse`.

Comment: Is the `set` here relevant? Isn't that just a convoluted way of doing `std::cout << (tp + 1s);`? Where the interesting part is that `tp` itself already differs?

Comment: I don't believe the `set` is relevant.  I did my testing by just streaming out `tp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcc-13 version is calling `date::parse`, and the gcc-trunk version is calling `std::chrono::parse`.  These are supposed to do the same thing, but are independent implementations.

Yesterday I filed https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=114244 which is in this area, but may or may not impact this specific example.

See the comment below by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo) for a good explanation of this behavior.

Comment: The reason trunk doesn't pick `date::parse` is because of ambiguity when selecting `date::from_stream`  overload - which can be circumvented by using it directly `date::from_stream(in, "%Y%m%d-%T", tp);` instead.